# ASP.Net: why is my button's click/command events not binding/firing in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-2.0, repeater, button

Here's the code from the ascx that has the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ListOfEmails" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate><h3>A sub-header:</h3></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        [Some other stuff is here]
        <asp:Button ID="removeEmail" runat="server" Text="X" ToolTip="remove" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in the codebehind for the repeater's databound and events:

```
Protected Sub ListOfEmails_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles ListOfEmails.ItemDataBound
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
        Dim removeEmail As Button = CType(e.Item.FindControl("removeEmail"), Button)
        removeEmail.CommandArgument = e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString()

        AddHandler removeEmail.Click, AddressOf removeEmail_Click
        AddHandler removeEmail.Command, AddressOf removeEmail_Command
    End If
End Sub

Sub removeEmail_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Response.Write("<h1>click</h1>")
End Sub

Sub removeEmail_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
    Response.Write("<h1>command</h1>")
End Sub
```

Neither the click or command is getting called, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Controls nested inside of Repeaters do not intercept events. Instead you need to bind to the `Repeater.ItemCommand` Event.

[`ItemCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand) contains [`RepeaterCommandEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatercommandeventargs) which has two important fields:

- CommandName
- CommandArgument

So, a trivial example:

```cs
void rptr_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        // Stuff to databind
        Button myButton = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("myButton");

        myButton.CommandName = "Add";
        myButton.CommandArgument = "Some Identifying Argument";
    }
}

void rptr_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Add")
    {
        // Do your event
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to handle the [ItemCommand event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx) on your Repeater. Here's [an example](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3609466).

Then, your button clicks will be handled by the ListOfEmails_ItemCommand method. I don't think wiring up the Click or Command event (of the button) in ItemDataBound will work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning to use ItemCommand event, make sure you register to ItemCommand event in Page_Init not in Page_Load.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // rptr is your repeater's name
    rptr.ItemCommand += new RepeaterCommandEventHandler(rptr_ItemCommand);
}
```

I am not sure why it wasn't working for me with this event registered in Page_Load but moving it to Page_Init helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an experiment for you to try:

Set a breakpoint on ListOfEmails_ItemDataBound and see if it's being called for postbacks.

Comment: why? Could you elaborate? I don't really think this counts as an 'answer' maybe you should have rather added this as a 'comment'.

Answer (score 0):

You know what's frustrating about this?

If you specify an OnClick in that asp:Button tag, the build *will* verify that the named method exists in the codebehind class, and report an error if it doesn't... even though that method will never get called.