# How to fire a button event from inside a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, onclick, repeater, itemcommand

I have done my research but can't find an efficient way to do the following in **VB**:

- Each button should fire the same event.
- The button event saves **every** repeater item and so each event is **not** unique.

I am aware I can use the ItemCommand option but have not been able to get it working as desired.

**ASP.NET**

*Inside Repeater Item*

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" RunAt="Server"/>
```

**VB.NET**

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    sqlConn.Open()
        For Each Item As RepeaterItem In rpt.Items
        ...
        Next
    sqlConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:**

After some research here on SO, I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396/asp-net-why-is-my-buttons-click-command-events-not-binding-firing-in-a-repeate) that others events than `ItemCommand` are not caught by `Asp:Repeater`, as [FlySwat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1965/flyswat) said on his answer. So you'll need to write your `VB.NET` code like this:

First, declare the `ItemCommand` event on your page with something like this:

```
Protected Sub rpt_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles rpt.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Save" Then
        'Save
    End If
End Sub
```

Then, on `Asp:Button` markup inside the `Asp:Repeater`, you must set its `CommandName` property like this:

```
<Asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CommandName="Save" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
```

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to learn more about the `UseSubmitBehavior`.

Try it.

Comment: Yes I had already tried that although I had not added the with events. Still this seems not to be working for my situations. Thanks for the assistance though.

Comment: But, what happens? The click event is not being fired?

Comment: Well, after some research on SO, I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396/asp-net-why-is-my-buttons-click-command-events-not-binding-firing-in-a-repeate). There [FlySwat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1965/flyswat) explains that the only `Event` that can be raised inside an `Asp:Repeater` is the `ItemCommand`. Please, take a look. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Usually, we use CommandArgument to store some value, so it's implying on the event hasn't being fired. How the page is behaving? Is it posting back? What's happening when you debug?

Comment: Try to set the `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` `Button`'s property. I think it will work now.

Comment: And it was as simple as that. Many Thanks for your efforts Alexandre.

Answer (score 5):

When the button is inside a Repeater template, you need to add OnClick event, you can add event on `ItemDataBound event` of the Repeater control.

Your .aspx code will look something like this:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button  ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="SomeText" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code-behind

```
void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == Repeater1.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == Repeater1.Item)
    {
        var btn = e.Item.FindControl("btnSave") as Button;
        if (btn != null)
        {  // adding button event 
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        }
    }
}

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //write your code 
}
```

in vb.net

```
Private Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.ItemType = Repeater1.AlternatingItem OrElse e.Item.ItemType = Repeater1.Item Then
        Dim btn = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("btnSave"), Button)
        If btn IsNot Nothing Then
            ' adding button event 
            btn.Click += New EventHandler(btn_Click)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'write your code 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sain but as I mentioned above I have done my research. I found this example on google already and I needed a vb solution I'm not very good with c#.