# OnClick Event for panel which is inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Panel id="contactsListContainer" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="contactsListRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Panel CssClass="contactsList" ID="contactList" runat="server" OnClick="contactLink_Click" CommandArgument='<%# ((AddressBook.Employee)Container.DataItem).Id %>' CausesValidation="false">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblContactName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblContactEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblContactMobile" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MobileNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:Panel>
```

I want to add onclick event for contactlist panel. how can i add it.

This is the code what is to be done when that panel is clicked.

```
 protected void contactLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contactsForm.Style.Add("display", "none");
        detailsContainer.Style.Add("display", "block");
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        SelectEmpId = int.Parse(btn.CommandArgument);
        LinkButton contactListLinkButton = getSelctedLinkButton();
        contactListLinkButton.Style.Add("background-color", "#CEE7F2");
        Employee employee = GetEmployee(SelectEmpId);
        lblDetailName.Text = employee.Name;
        lblDetailAddress.Text = employee.Address;
        lblDetailMobile.Text = employee.MobileNumber;
        lblDetailLandline.Text = employee.LandLineNumber;
        lblDetailEmail.Text = employee.Email;
        lblDetailWebsite.Text = employee.Website;
        lblDetailAddress.Text = employee.Address;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `OnClick` event for Asp.NET `Panel`, try this instead:

You can refer to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20540854/4779385

Hope it helps!

Comment: This won't work inside a repeater as in his example, because he will have multiple items with the same client-side ID and the jQuery selector will not work.

Comment: Yeah, figures. Updated it, though.

Answer (score 0):

The `<asp:Panel>` does not have a Click event you can handle.

Although you will probably have some CSS work to do, a good approach is to wrap the content you want to be server-clickable inside an HTML anchor, i.e.

```
<a id="anchor" runat="server">
  .. your stuff
</a>
```

You can add a Clicked handler to the anchor inside the repeater/grid's ItemDataBound event, and specify your contactLink_Click handler is the one to handle the event for all anchors/panels in the repeater/grid.

(this example is from a repeater, adapt it for a GridView)

```
void contactsListRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.Item;

    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        var anchor = item.FindControl("anchor") as HtmlAnchor;
        anchor.ServerClick += contactLink_Click;
    }
}
```

Note that the `sender` will be the anchor that raises the click event, so you can drill down into the correct child controls from `sender` (if you need to)